# Are mandatory notifications GDPR compliant?

Tags: web-app, notification, applications, user-preferences

I have designed a notification center for my app.
I would like to make sure users can't turn - off some types of in-app notifications: comments and replies.

Our app should be GDPR compliant. Is it okay to keep some of the notification types mandatory?  Should users be able to turn-off all in-app notifications?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking can also be categorised as **"User Consent"**. As per GDPR, it is mandatory to take the Consent of the user to collect data and use the data for push notification.

However, in-app messaging, which is considered as part of the app experience, does not actually require an opt-in from the user. Although, be careful, as not all in-app messaging is classed as user experience and would still need consent if this channel is being used purely for marketing.

Here is an in-depth article [link](https://mobilemarketingmagazine.com/consent-is-key-for-in-app-messaging-compliance-and-success) that I found useful. Hope this helps you.